# NPM downloads nodejs each time

Tags: node.js, npm, fedora

I use fedora, so I had nodejs and npm installed from the repos.

But I needed to install SailsJS which asked for newer versioon of npm, so I did a `sudo npm install npm -g`, but after that installing each package takes a lot of time and in verbose mode I can see that each time nodejs is fetched and compiled (even though my fedora already has the same version installed). Some output :

```
npm verb linkBins utf-8-validate@1.1.0
npm verb linkMans utf-8-validate@1.1.0
npm verb rebuildBundles utf-8-validate@1.1.0
npm verb rebuildBundles [ 'bindings', 'nan' ]
npm info install utf-8-validate@1.1.0

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install /lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'node',
gyp verb cli   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.36 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: v0.10.36
gyp verb command install [ 'v0.10.36' ]
gyp verb install input version string "v0.10.36"
gyp verb install installing version: 0.10.36
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/0.10.36"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/.node-gyp"
gyp verb command install [ 'v0.10.36' ]
gyp verb install input version string "v0.10.36"
gyp verb install installing version: 0.10.36
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 0.10.36
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/.node-gyp/0.10.36
gyp verb created nodedir /lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/.node-gyp
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/node-v0.10.36.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/node-v0.10.36.tar.gz
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/zlib.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/deflate.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/inflate.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/zutil.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/examples/gzlog.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/crc32.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/inffast.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/trees.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball deps/zlib/gzguts.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to have the solution proposed here :https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/610 
Basically you have to download node v0.10.36 in the .node-gyp directory.